# How to Insert a row and return autoincrement value in sqlite in wp?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have an app using sqlite client. In the app i insert the data in a table and i need the Id which is autoincreament. Is there anyway to get the id in executenonquery? s.th like sqlparameter or ...

I am using the following method to fetch data and i thought rec variable hold the id but it is always rec=1 and i dont know what this is good for?

```
             int x= (System.Windows.Application.Current as App).db.Insert
<CsWidget>(ObjWidget, @"Insert into Tbl_Widget (Name) values(@Name");

             public int Insert<T>(T obj, string statement) where T : new()
                    {
                            Open();
                            SQLiteCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand(statement);               
                            int rec = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(obj);
                             return rec;
                     }
```

Comment: I even added SELECT last_insert_rowid() at the end of my statement but i dont know how to fetch this value

Comment: Unrelated comment: dear god why use an RDMBS with staight-up SQL commands on a mobile device. Just use Linq2SQL.

Comment: I am new to windows development and that is what i found as "good reference". so It would be nice if you can send me a more strait links/references i can start with

Comment: Follow this tutorial @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx and here's the downloadable sample for that article @ http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Local-Database-Sample-57b1614c

Answer (score 0):

Try ExecuteScalar method instead of ExecuteNonQuery. It can work that way depending on your SQLite wrapper. If not the separate query after insert is your only way.

Comment: I tried ExecuteScalar but it returns null. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think nothing. ExecuteScalar may also not working in this case. It is depending on realization of the wrapper library.

Answer (score 0):

As @gleb.kudr said, a separate query after the insert is the only way.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ROWID()";

object r = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

int id = 0;
int.TryParse( r.ToString(), out id );
```

Comment: i tried this as well it returns error "bind or column index out of range" in executescalar().  It drove me crazy. have any suggesstion?